# Drag and select broken on one monitor on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 21.04

Before upgrading, drag and select worked just fine on both monitors, but now on one of the monitors, I get this weird behaviour that the selection area that should follow the cursor does not take into consideration the horizontal offset?

Here's a screen recording of the weird behaviour: https://youtu.be/nC6pIn6uKgc

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: @David, I did report it back in april, and it is fixed by now.